# GRUB2: Installing a new bootloader without interacting with other disks or existing grub2 installs

Tags: grub2, boot-loader

While most questions about GRUB2 are about it not detecting such and such OS, I want on the contrary to stop GRUB2 from interacting with everything on my machine.

### Context & Problem

The problem appears when I configure a new Linux install on a disk (let's call it `/dev/sdb`) by chrooting to it from another install on another disk (`/dev/sda`). I am chrooted into the new system and run:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id="Void Linux [GRUB]" --recheck
```

I am following the set of instructions from [Void Linux Wiki](https://wiki.voidlinux.org/Install_LVM_LUKS_on_UEFI_GPT) by the way.

After running the command, my BIOS sees the new disk but no longer the old one. I can patch things up afterwards by chrooting into the old system from the new one and reinstall GRUB2 from there. Afterwards, the BIOS sees both disks independently. This is of course an unsatisfactory fix.

### Note

- The `bootloader-id` is different from one disk to another, so the problem does not come from there.
- I use the following `/etc/default/grub`, I tried adding `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` (without success).

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Void"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=4 slub_debug=P page_poison=1 rd.auto=1"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `chroot`. Mounting the ESP prior to running `grub-install` should be sufficient. `grub-install` should pick it up automagically. Use `--no-nvram` to leave EFI variables untouched.

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --bootloader-id="Void Linux [GRUB]" --no-nvram /dev/sdb
```

`/etc/default/grub` is not used by grub-install. It is only relevant for `grub-mkconfig`. You did not mention `grub-mkconfig`, so I assume an unconfigured GRUB2 installation is what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks. `--no-nvram` does the trick of not clobbering the old setup.